# jQuery select box make option selected based on url

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, html-select

I have a select box as follows. How do i mark an option as selected based on the last part of the url. ex: http://domain.com/index/one. The last part of the url is one so i want option one to be selected.

```
<select>
    <option id="one">One</option>
    <option id="two">Two</option>
    <option id="three">Three</option>
</select>
```

I'm looking for jQuery or Javascript Solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var parts = window.location.href.split('/');
if (parts.length > 0) {
    $('#myselect').val(parts[parts.length - 1].split('?')[0]);
}
```

also make sure you fix your select and give values to your options, not ids:

```
<select id="myselect">
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do, assuming URL has that last part you mentioned ('one' as in your question)

```
$('#selectid').val(window.location.href.substring(
                      window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/')+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you're trying to do this with jquery/javascript?   would seem more logical to do this with whatever server side language you're using.   Maybe use a rewrite as well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for: `window.location`
Maybe parse a range from that url.

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/R48GY/